# MagicalRecord with UITableView Example

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, magicalrecord

Does anyone know if there's a good tutorial or example project with MagicalRecord setup in a TableView based app, preferably with some background thread stuff happening (importing data, and calling back to update the UI)? I haven't really been able to find any good samples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're still expecting an answer on this, but might still help others, I wrote a tutorial on the basic usage of CoreData: http://ablfx.com/blog/2012/03/using-coredata-magicalrecord/

And here is a sample App Showing Data in a TableView:
https://github.com/ablfx/MagicalRecord-Example-App

Answer (score 0):

Here's another general example I wrote http://www.dplusmpage.com/2012/07/13/coredata-on-ios-using-magicalrecord/ perhaps this helps. It's also about another problem I ran into the generation of NSManagedSubclasses.

Comment: Do you have a new link for this? Unfortunately wasn't archived on archive.org.